# GAE Datastore Structure

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, optimization, google-cloud-datastore

I have been using Google App Engine for a few months now and I have recently come to doubt some of my practices with regard to the Datastore.  I have around 10 entities with 10-12 properties each.  Everything works well in my app and the code is pretty straightforward with the way I have my data structured but I am wondering if I should break up these large entities into smaller ones for either optimization of reads and writes or just to follow best practices (which I am not sure of regarding GAE)

Right now I am over my quotas for reads and writes and would like to keep those in check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizing Reads:

- If you use an offset in a query, the offset entities are counted as reads. If you run a query where offset=100, the datastore retrieves and discards the first 100 entities and you are billed for those reads. Use cursors wherever possible to reduce read ops. Cursors will also result in faster queries.
- NDB won't necessarily reduce reads when you are running queries. Queries are made against the datastore and entities are returned, no memcache interaction occurs. If you want to retrieve entities from memcache in the context of a query, you will need to run a keys_only query and then attempt to retrieve those keys from memcache. You would then need to go to the datastore for any entities that were cache misses. Retrieving a key is a "small" op which is 1/7 the cost of a read op.

Optimizing Writes:

- Remove unused indexes. By default every property on your entity is indexed and each of those incurs 2 writes the first time it is written and 4 writes whenever it is modified. You can disable indexing for a property like so: firstname = db.StringProperty(indexed=False).
- If you use list properties, each item in the list is an individual property on the entity. The list properties are abstractions provided for convenience. A list property named things with the value ["thing1", "thing2"] is really two properties in the datastore: things_0="thing1" and things_1="things". This can get really expensive when combined with indexing.
- Consolidate properties that you don't need to query. If you only need to query on one or two properties, serialize the rest of those properties and store it as a blob on the entity.

Further reading:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Understanding_Write_Costs

Comment: More further reading (I don't have the street cred to post more than two links in an answer):

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Indexes_and_Properties

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113363/what-does-google-classify-as-a-datastore-write-operation-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into using NDB Entities. NDB will use the in-context cache (and Memcache if need be) before resorting to performing reads/writes to the Datastore. This should help you stay within your quota.

Read here for more information on how NDB uses caching: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache

And please consult this page for a discussion of best practices with regards to GAE: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/overview

Comment: I actually converted everything to NDB about two months ago and it definitely made a difference. good link on best practices too

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine Datastore charges a fixed amount per Entity read, no matter how large the Entity is (although there is a max of 1MB). This means it makes sense to combine multiple entities that you ofter read together into a single one. The downside is only that the latency increases (as it needs to deserialize a larger Entity each time). I found this latency to be quite low (low 1 digit ms even for large ones).

The use of frameworks ontop of Datastore is a good idea. I am using Objectify and am very happy. Use the Memcache integration with care though. Googles provides only a fixed limited amount of memory to each application, so as soon as you are talking about larger data this will not solve your problem (since Entities have been evicted from Memcache and need to be re-read from datastore and put into cache again for each read).

Comment: okay great thanks for that confirmation.  yes I have noticed some of the memcache limitations but overall it has been a big read saver.  do you know of anything like Objectify for Python?