# Updating existing entities: how do updates work under the hood re: costs?

Tags: google-app-engine

According to pricing docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing), updating an existing entity uses the following number of reads/writes:

```
Existing Entity Put (per entity):
1 write + 4 writes per modified indexed property value +
2 writes per modified composite index value
```

Say I have an entity with 20 properties that I want to update. In my code I update each on manually with something along the lines:

```
tmp_entity = ModelName.get(id="id")
tmp_entity.item1 = item1
tmp_entity.item2 = item2
.
.
.
tmp_entity.item20 = item20
tmp_entity.put()
```

Say for example only `item4` and `item17` changed. Does App Engine check if an entity is the same before charging reads, or does it assume that because I added a line like `tmp_entity.item = item` that I mean to update the value and charges reads?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are charged only for "modified" indexed properties, i.e. new, changed or removed properties. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113363/what-does-google-classify-as-a-datastore-write-operation-in-google-app-engine

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to flag my original as a duplicate and copy that link.