# Two different Datastore quotas for AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

### Per operation

[GAE Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore) article states that Datastore quota measured in read/write **operations** (for example when you put an entity several write operations [occurs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Understanding_write_costs) **per property**):

[image: GAE Quotas]

The same is at [GAE Home page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/):

[image]

---

### Per entity

At the same time [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls) article states that quota measured in read/write **per entity** ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38136385/3084258) there is information that it's appeared recently):

[image: App Engine Pricing]

---

### Experimenting

In Google Cloud Console at App Engine Quotas tab there are details both for *Datastore Write Operations* and *Datastore Entity Writes*; putting an entity works fine when the first one exceeds its limit (I reached the limit and then put new entity to check, there is no billing enabled for the project):

[image]

My question is what is the real quota restrictions in GAE Datastore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of July 1, 2016, Cloud Datastore quotas and billing are based on **entity** reads and writes (and deletes) instead of read and write operations. The [third link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#costs-for-datastore-calls) you provided in your question shows the correct information.

The other pages are out of date and should be updated shortly. Thanks for pointing them out!